# Apache httpd, WebDAV entries to give access to a directory

Tags: httpd, mod-webdav

After having enabled WebDav on an Apache httpd 2.2, i want to give access to a specific directory (that has not to do with other sites managed by httpd). 
What is the smallest set of entries to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The docs [suggest something like this](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_dav.html) would get you started under the default virtual host, once you have installed the module

```
DavLockDB /usr/local/apache2/var/DavLock

Alias /foo /home/my/files/directory
<Location /foo>
Dav On

AuthType Basic
AuthName DAV
AuthUserFile user.passwd

<LimitExcept GET OPTIONS>
require user admin
</LimitExcept>
</Location>
```